# Update an existing role's iam policy through cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

is there a way that i could update an existing roles iam (inline) policy.

Process followed for now:

1) I am able to create an role

2) I am able to attach a managed policy

3) I am able to attach an inline policy

I accept 2 parameters in the script one is an `externalid` and another is the `role name`. If the enduser or customer specifies an input for an existing role then i would have update the existing role's IAM Policy and i have to add new aws services to the existing policy

Thanks
Nataraj

Comment: Short answer is - yes you can update both the role (add or delete managed/inline policies) & policy using CFN. If you are using console, you use the `update stack` action to do this. Using CLI, use the `update-stack` command - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/update-stack.html. Maybe you need to add more details to your question to get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straightforward with update stack.

[ASR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8502552/asr) Thank you very much for your input